# Removing None from Python list of lists

Tags: python, list, nonetype

I have a list that looks like this:

```
[None, None, None, None, [(u'data1', 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, '2015-10-01', '2015-10-01')], None, None, None, None, [(u'data2', 8.0, 5.0, 0.625, 1.25, '2015-10-01', '2015-10-01')], None, None, None, None, None, None, [(u'data3', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, '2015-10-01', '2015-10-01')], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

I need to remove the None's so i can iterate through the list. Should I not insert if the value is None, or just remove them from the list after they are inserted?

I am building the list like this:

```
item = (val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, start_date, end_date)
array.append(item)
```

The first 5 values are the ones that will return None.  But looking at the data, sometimes it only inserts 4 None's, sometimes 5.

I have tried several solutions from stack, such as:

```
[x for x in result is not None]
```

and

```
if val is not None:
    item = (val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, start_date, end_date)
    array.append(item)
```

but for some reason, it will still append even if the val is None.

Comment: What is val exactly? You test if val is not None, and then you continue adding something else, namely 'item' to your array.

Comment: How did `if val is not None` not work?

Comment: so i think i have a little more info, val is a response from an api call. What i think is happening is when there is no data it returned "{u'responseAggregationType': u'byProperty'}" and then inserted none for the other values i was looking for.

Comment: a good response is something like "{u'rows': [{u'keys': [u'8 bit music'], u'impressions': 178.0, u'clicks': 12.0, u'ctr': 0.06741573033707865, u'position': 3.6179775280898876}], u'responseAggregationType': u'byProperty'}".

Comment: so i tried doing "val = response['rows'] and then if val is not None:', but i get a keyerror that rows dne

Comment: you are adding the values so you should never have to filter anything if you filter before you add, None should never be added to your list, pretty sure `if response:...` may do the filtering for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your list comprehension.

```
results = [None, None, None, None, [(u'data1', 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, '2015-10-01', '2015-10-01')], None, None, None, None, [(u'data2', 8.0, 5.0, 0.625, 1.25, '2015-10-01', '2015-10-01')], None, None, None, None, None, None, [(u'data3', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, '2015-10-01', '2015-10-01')], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
results = [result for result in results if result is not None]
>>> [[(u'data1', 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, '2015-10-01', '2015-10-01')], [(u'data2', 8.0, 5.0, 0.625, 1.25, '2015-10-01', '2015-10-01')], [(u'data3', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, '2015-10-01', '2015-10-01')]]
```

Comment: ty, I did this exaclty and was able to pass results to itertools and turn it into one list of lists for mysql mass insert.

Answer (score 3):

you are missing a piece of your list comprehension

```
[x for x in result if x is not None]
```

Comment: `if val is not None:` should have worked so there has to be more to the question

Comment: @PadraicCunningham what else could there be to the question. I tried it with his exact list and it worked.  Maybe `val` does not related to `val1`, `val2` like we think or `array` is not starting empty.

Comment: yeah sorry, val isn't related to the other vals

Comment: @cmd, the filtering would not be needed at all if the OP did not add Nones ,they created the list so it should be possible to not add them in the first place hence why I said `if val is not None` should have worked if val is what they are adding

Comment: @PadraicCunningham true, but since the code that is adding `None` isn't included...

Comment: yep, that is the part of the question that is missing