# Python: How to iterate over a list of lists and delete None's?

Tags: python

I want to iterate over a list of lists and delete None's from every list:

List of lists:

```py
my_list = [src_ips, dst_ips, src_fqdns, dst_fqdns, src_groups, dst_groups, services, service_groups]
```

I tried:

```py
src_ips = [i for i in src_ips if i is not None]
dst_ips = [i for i in dst_ips if i is not None]
src_fqdns = [i for i in src_fqdns if i is not None]
dst_fqdns = [i for i in dst_fqdns if i is not None]
src_groups = [i for i in src_groups if i is not None]
dst_groups = [i for i in dst_groups if i is not None]
services = [i for i in services if i is not None]
service_groups = [i for i in service_groups if i is not None]
```

It works, but I would like to use something shorter, it's too long. What is the solution?

Comment: `[[i for i in lst if i is not None] for lst in my_list]`

Comment: `def f(l): return [i for i in l if i is not None]` `src_ips = f(src_ips)`…?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing None from Python list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978128/removing-none-from-python-list-of-lists)

Comment: Is it necessary to have each list in it's own separate variable? If you need to manipulate all these together, a dictionary would likely be a better holder, and you can easily iterate over the keys while reassigning values to them.

Comment: Note that `my_list = [src_ips, dst_ips, ...` is a list with the values stored in `src_ips, dst_ips, ...`, not a list of names referencing those values.

Comment: Also, if you have lists of values that need cleaning, and likely future processing... have you considered using dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in `for` loop like this:

```py
for l in [src_ips, dst_ips, src_fqdns, dst_fqdns, src_groups, dst_groups, services, service_groups]:
    l[:] = [element for element in l if element is not None]
```